# Почему в массив записывается только 1 число?

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    const int N = 5, M = 6;
    int Z[N][M] = { {-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6 },

                { 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5 },

                { 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5 },

                { 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5 },

                { 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5 } }, i, j, k, B[6];

    k = 0;
    std::cout << "Массив B: " << std::endl;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) 
        {
            if (Z[j][i] < 0) 
            {
                if (k == 0) 
                {
                    B[i] = Z[j][i];
                    std::cout << B[i] << std::endl;
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему в массив записывается только 1 число?

Сколько раз при подходе к этому блоку `k` будет равно нулю?

```
            if (k == 0) 
            {
                B[i] = Z[j][i];
                std::cout << B[i] << std::endl;
                k++;
            }
```

Comment: понял, спасибо.